# trying to make a pyramid with nested list with sub-list lengths increasing by 1

Tags: python

I am doing this assignment for a python course but I am nowhere near the solution.

Let's say if I enter x = 4, this is what I am supposed to get:

```
        "pyramid(0) =>" [ ]
        "pyramid(1) =>" [ [1] ]
        "pyramid(2) =>" [ [1], [1, 1] ]
        "pyramid(3) =>" [ [1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1] ]
```

I believe the logic is similar when making triangle's right side, right?

this is my code, but I am missing something, hope you guys could point me to the right direction and the task's logic.
Thank you!

```
x = 4
list1 = []
line = 0
while line < x:
    one = line + 1
    while one > 0:
        list1.append(1)
        one -= 1
    line += 1
    print(list1)
```

Comment: You only have one list in total. You need to create more lists.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
def pyramid(n):
    result = []
    for i in range(n):
        result.append([1] * (i+1))
    return result

>>> pyramid(0)
[]
>>> pyramid(1)
[[1]]
>>> pyramid(2)
[[1], [1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to come up with words to guide you to this solution, but it just wasn't possible.  You need a 'for' loop to count to 4, and you need `[1]*i` to create a list with a certain number of 1s.

```
x = 4
list1 = []
print("pyramid(0) =>", list1)
for i in range(x):
    list1.append( [1] * i )
    print("pyramid(%d) =>" % (i+1), list1)
```

Answer (score 0):

As @mkrieger1 stated, you need more lists. Create the sublist in you for loop, then add to that sublist instead of adding to `list`. Then you can add the sublist to `list1`. This can keep your structure intact.

```py
x = 4
list1 = []
line = 0
while line < x:
    one = line + 1
    sublist = []  # create the sublist to be added
    while one > 0:
        sublist.append(1)  # grow the sublist to the right size
        one -= 1
    list1.append(sublist)  # add the sublist into the printed list
    line += 1
    print(list1)
```